# log4j Parquet Java Error ADF Integration Runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm getting an error in a self-hosted Integration Runtime for Azure Data Factory, specifically `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/log4j/Level`. This is the full error generated by ADF:

```
Operation on target QCR Load failed: Operation on target Copy failed: ErrorCode=ParquetJavaInvocationException,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=An error occurred when invoking java, message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache/log4j/Level
total entry:13
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
org.apache.parquet.Log.<init>(Log.java:62)
org.apache.parquet.Log.getLog(Log.java:56)
org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat.<clinit>(FilterCompat.java:43)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader$Builder.<init>(ParquetReader.java:174)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader$Builder.<init>(ParquetReader.java:164)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.builder(ParquetReader.java:161)
com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetBatchReaderBridge.open(ParquetBatchReaderBridge.java:62)
com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetFileBridge.createReader(ParquetFileBridge.java:22)
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.log4j.Level
total entry:17
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:128)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:107)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:295)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
org.apache.parquet.Log.<init>(Log.java:62)
org.apache.parquet.Log.getLog(Log.java:56)
org.apache.parquet.filter2.compat.FilterCompat.<clinit>(FilterCompat.java:43)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader$Builder.<init>(ParquetReader.java:174)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader$Builder.<init>(ParquetReader.java:164)
org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetReader.builder(ParquetReader.java:161)
com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetBatchReaderBridge.open(ParquetBatchReaderBridge.java:62)
com.microsoft.datatransfer.bridge.parquet.ParquetFileBridge.createReader(ParquetFileBridge.java:22)
.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.ParquetTransferPlugin,''Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.JniExt.JavaBridgeException,Message=,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Richfile.HiveOrcBridge,'
```

It is specifically when executing a Copy Activity against a Parquet file.

I can see the log4j jars are in the Integration Runtime Jars directory:
[image: Screenshot of Jars folder]

I haven't found any good documentation on this except for an [Informatica snippet](https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/152368?language=en_US) that suggests the following:

> There are 3 lo4j*.jar files used by Informatica Data Replication (IDR), as follows:

> - log4j-1.2.16.jar
> - log4jdbc3-1.2beta2.jar
> - log4jdbc4-1.2beta2.jar

> To resolve this issue, ensure that the three Java files are available in the DBSYNC_HOME\lib directory and then re-run the IDR console.

Has anyone encountered this error before? I'm running Microsoft Integration Runtime v5.0 on a self-hosted machine. I'd think that slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5 would cover this dependency, am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Integration Runtime was missing the log4j-1.2.17 jar file. Simply installing that jar onto the IR and recycling the service fixed this problem